# Rails cron job between midnight and 1am ET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I'm using `sidekiq-ent` gem to schedule cron jobs. I want to use schedule a task which will run between midnight and 1am ET. What cron syntax should I use?

```
  config.periodic do |mgr|
    # every day between midnight and 1 ET

    mgr.register("0 0-1 * * *", ExampleWorker)
   end
```

Don't know how to test this, but is `0 0-1 * * *` correct?

Comment: https://crontab.guru/#0_0-1_*_*_*

Comment: Take a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/162388/what-does-five-asterisks-in-a-cron-file-mean#answer-601660

Comment: @KevinEtore so mine is correct is in it?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Do you want it to run once every day at a random time (random is not supported in cron)? or do you want to run it two times, one at 00:00 and one at 01:00 which is what you've made.

Answer (score 0):

based on this documentation https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Periodic-Jobs

there are 2 ways

1. you can set global time zone

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.periodic do |mgr|

    # "global" custom timezome, will affect any further registered jobs
    mgr.tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Kathmandu")
    mgr.register("* 4 * * *", "KathmanduWorker") # 4AM in Kathmandu
    mgr.register("* 5 * * *", "KathmanduWorker") # 5AM in Kathmandu
```

2. custom time zone for each job

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.periodic do |mgr|
    mgr.register("* 4 * * *", "TokyoWorker", tz: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Tokyo"))
```